# How to set UITableViewCell accessory size?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting the accessory in code like

```
cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

but I'd like it to be a bit larger on some devices. I'm already changing cell height in code, but the size of the checkbox stays the same.

Answer (score 9):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` and in `layoutSubviews` adjust the accessory like so:

```
if self.accessoryView != nil {
   let accessory = self.accessoryView
   accessory.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
}
```

Where x, y, width, and height can be anything you want really as long as they are CGFloats.

Comment: I don't know how I can subclass `UITableViewCell`. I'm setting the accessoryType in `UITableViewController`

Comment: You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and set accessoryType in `awakeFromNib` @TimSim

Comment: This is too complicated for me, I don't know what's `awakeFromNib` or what Nib is, I don't know what to put in `layoutSubviews()` in the new class, I don't know how to make the table use the new class, I just want to change the size of the icon.

Comment: As an alternative, you can make your own `accessoryView` by not setting one in code or interface builder and using `cell.contentView.addSubview(view)` where "view" is your custom created UIView. (do this in `cellForRowAt`) @TimSim

Comment: Sorry, none of that helps me. :( I need to change the size of the icon. Maybe someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: @TimSim this is a pretty straight-forward and clear answer.   It sounds like you need to do some more study of how tableviews work and how to override classes, such as UITableViewCell. I am sure there are lots of tutorials if you search.

Comment: I'm sure it's pretty straightforward for someone who's good at programming. I don't think I should accept an answer that I can't understand or implement, and I can't afford to spend a few hours studying how to change the size of an icon.

Comment: why is self.accessoryView returning nil?

Comment: "I can't afford to spend a few hours studying how to change the size of an icon". That comment doesn't fit well in the world of software development. R&D! You _must_ spend hours beating your head against a problem until you find the solution. Take care and joy in what you're building. The provided answer is _exactly_ what you need. Now you just need to do a bit more research on the fundamentals of programming. "Class Inheritance". "Subclassing". "Virtual methods". This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. I came here with the same question, so thank you @Ike10